# Visualforce list using Apex function and parameter

Tags: apex, visualforce, list, repeat

So at the moment I have a VisualForce Page that uses the following code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="RelationshipTreeController">
    <apex:repeat value="{!nameToRelationType}" var="name">
        <apex:repeat value="{!nameToRelationType[name]}" var="relationType">
            <apex:outputText value="{!name} ({!relationType})"/>
            <br></br>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

And an extension controller with a Map`<String, List<String>>` nameToRelationType.
The constructor will populate the map and the VF page lists the contents of the map using the nested `<apex:repeat`s

What I would prefer though is to take those keys and just make a List`<String>` with them. Then the first repeat in the VF page will iterate through that List and within there it will call a function passing in the current String from the List and the function will create the List`<String>` that would have been the value in the map and return it. Sadly though I cannot call a function with a paramter using `<apex:repeat` and I cannot use the `<apex:param` since it cannot be a child of `<apex:repeat`. So does anyone have any insight? I am pretty new to Salesforce

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking to do is not possible. From what I understand, basically you would prefer to do something like this:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!keyList}" var="key">
    <apex:repeat value="{!functionToGenerateList(key)}" var="val">
        // do some stuff related to the val
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Unfortunately, this isn't possible since you can not pass parameters back to Visualforce like that.

The way you are currently doing this is what I would consider best practice. It may feel a bit weird, but if you are new to Salesforce development, you will quickly learn to get really familiar with [`Map`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm). It is utilized heavily. There is some [documentation on working with them in Visualforce](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_dynamic_vf_maps_lists.htm?SearchType=Stem), but you are already doing it properly.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't feel weird necessarily since it worked perfectly. I was just hoping to optimize and get rid of the overhead of the map by using the function. Good to know though

Comment: I know exactly what you mean @LouisPujol. I have gone through that same process before for this where I tried to clean it up a bit, and it felt odd that what I did was kind of the best way to do it.